# Incorrectly result of pytesseract(python)

Tags: python, python-tesseract, opencv

I has a script for reading text from image on base `pytesseract` python library for converting image to text on it. I open image with photo of coin and apply `image_to_string` method for return text on image.(Image has a text on Russian and beforehand I load `rus.traineddata` for correctly detecting of text on Russian.But result of both side of coins(images) in console is empty.Pytesseract returns nothing.I tried to change color of image with cv2 library and result so awful, return text, which not on image.Bellow I provide my las version for code, and an images of coins.
Result of script in console must include text(On Russian) 
 1 image:`"Банк России 10 Рублей"`,
2 image: `"Никто не забыт, ничто не забыто"`

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy
avers, revers = ('coinaversTEST.jpeg', 'coinreversTEST.jpeg')
aver = Image.open(avers)
rever = Image.open(revers)
color = cv2.cvtColor(numpy.array(rever), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(color, config='--psm 7 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789.%',
                                  lang="rus").strip())
```

...And Images.
[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4L0l.jpg)
[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I83oX.jpg)

Comment: I'd try cropping and rotating the area of interest, as `pytesseract` (I think) isn't trained on this kind of low contrast and angled texts.

Comment: I need to increase image contrast, right?

Comment: `tesseract` (the libary doing the actual work below `pytesseract`) can only detect straight text. So detecting the curved parts of the text won't work. You have to transform that parts of the image manually to be straight.

Comment: @АлексндрБосов, I'm not sure since it's bold letters, only the outer part of the letter have a contrast. It's like a character is outlined. I'd "unwrap" the image along the middle point like **Cube** said and checked if the results are good enough.